# Stop Sending email and Success Message

Tags: php, validation, email

Hi I am a beginner and php. I have used this validation example from w3 schools...The form is validating and sending the mail correctly. However. If i press submit without filling anything. It still sends an empty email. How to prevent it from not sending email unless all the fields are filled...Also how to show a Thank you message once everything is validated. I am very new to php. It would be great if you guys can copy my code and fiddle it. So that i can copy paste.

Mail to Function code:

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname:</th>
<th>Email:</th>
<th>Interest:</th>
<th>comment:</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$name</td>
<td>$email</td>
<td>$int</td>
<td>$comment</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";
?>


<?php
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

validation code:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $intErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $int = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["int"])) {
     $intErr = "Interest is required";
   } else {
     $int = test_input($_POST["int"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$int)) {
       $intErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
     $genderErr = "Gender is required";
   } else {
     $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you to do the form validation on client side using javascript, and not on server side. It would help server to bear less load. You can search on Google how to validate form using javascript before submitting.

If you still wish to do it on server side, then the moment you find an empty field, you can simply redirect the user to form page using "Header", with showing the empty field and asking them to fill it again. (You can again see the importance of Javascript, it would save the user his/her time to wait for server response).

```
header("Location:Your-FormFile-Name");
```

Only when everything is filled and not empty, you use mail function.

Answer (score 0):

:-)

Hi buddy in your both page code is looking fine. but have no relation.

your html form is not submitted without form tag. and validation code file is not call in html page. When you refresh your page then mail is automatically goes.

please check this link this help you..
http://www.formget.com/jquery-login-form/

Comment: I get this error when i try to submit data. Im using Javascript validation

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/content/99/10169899/html/demo/include/fgcontactform.php on line 548

here is the code on that line.   return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email);

Comment: a form is submited only when you use <form></form> tag in your form. But i can't see a form tag .  <form name="form1" method="post"><table></table></form>